# How to convert a list of numbers to a json

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, text, logic

How to convert list of numbers in a text file in to a valid json.
For example  I have a list of numbers in a text file like:

`1234, 1235,....`

I want it to be converted to JSON structure like

```
data : [{
   code : "1234"
   },
  { 
   code: "1235"
  },....
]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) (and get a badge). Your question lacks any attempt at solving this problem on your own. The idea is for you to try to get something to work and then come here with specific problems you are unable to resolve. Taking the tour and reading about [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the help center will provide all the information you need.

Comment: What you are calling JSON is NOT JSON. It is a malformed key/value pair that should be wrapped in `{}` - then it would be an object literal. You will need to read the file and do the necessary work to create this object.

Comment: Did you already read in the lines from the file or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have the contents of the file, split it by commas and then map it to objects:

```js
const fileContents = `1234, 1235`;

const result = fileContents
  .split(',')
  .map(x => ({
    code: x
  }));
  
console.dir(result);
```

You can get the contents of a file in node using `fs.readFile`, [the sync version](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_file_options) is slightly simpler though.

Answer (score 0):

```
// There is a built-in Module or in-built library in NodeJs which handles all 
// the reading operations called fs (File-System)   
// Requiring fs module in which 
// readFile function is defined. 

const fs = require('fs')

fs.readFile('input.txt', (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;

    let dataArray = data.toString().split(", ");
    let dataObjectArray = dataArray.map(data => {
        return { code: data }
    });
    console.log(dataObjectArray); // will give desired output
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    const file= '1234,...' ;

var jsonModel = file
  .split(',')
  .map(x => {
    code: x.trim() 
  });

var jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonModel)
```